# Hadoop : My reducer output is the same as mapper, though " INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 100%"

Tags: java, hadoop

I am able to execute mapper, But my reducer dosen't work. I even tried to debug, where my console is just going to the reducer's class and then coming out without entering the reduce method.Can anyone suggest me some solution to come out of this wierd situation ?

Comment: It would help if you could attach a nicely formatted copy of your source.  I'd suggest starting with the code that configures the mapper and reducer.

Comment: You are not writing any output from map class to reducer.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I got the answer when I changed Iterator<> in the reduce class to Iterable<> !! Would have seen the api before asking the question. But, very much thankful for your time..